# Android Listview with dynamic background colors

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a Listview that gets data from SQL. The data is RGB color codes. How can i set each listview item to a background color of the data it holds? That is

```
-------------------
 255,0,0                <- This items background color is red
-------------------
 0,255,0                <- This items background color is green
-------------------
```

And when new data is added the data item added should have a background color of the data it holds.

This is my code

```
public void loadListData(String item) {
    // database handler
    DB_Handler db = new DB_Handler(getContext());
    //get spinner item
    String selected_spinner;
    selected_spinner = item;

    List<String> lables = db.getSpinnerItemColors(selected_spinner);

    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lables);
    color_listview.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

Comment: you can make your own listener class for listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly you should define a structure hold color data, for example:
class ColorInfo{public int red, green, blue;}

query database and fill the result to an array which carry colorinfos: ArrayList arr;

define an adapter class for listview, the most important part is the getView() function:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // Get the data item for this position
   ColorInfo cinfo = getItem(position);    
   // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
   if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
   }
   // change it's background color depend on color info
   converView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(cinfo.red,cinfo,green,cinfo.blue));
   return convertView;
```

}

about how to get color value from rgb, check this out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

I saw your code, I think you can just create an anonymous adapter like this:

```
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lables){
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // do things what you want like change background color
}};
```

you may better firstly check what "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" // is in your %ANDROID_HOME_SDK%\platforms\android-x\data\res\layout directory

Comment: Is there a way around using an adapter class?

Comment: I guess you have used the CursorAdapter, you can extends CursorAdapter and override it's "bindview" function like this: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter
  public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {},

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
   .....
   parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fffff"));
   ....
 }
```

Several choices to do this...

**Set background to green:**

v.setBackgroundColor(0x00FF00);

v.invalidate();

**Set background to green with Alpha:**

v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);

v.invalidate();

Comment: is this for use in an custom adapter?

Answer (score 0):

**call this method inside Parsing class**

[image]

```
messages.clear();

for (Message message : response.body()) 
{
     // generate a random color
     // TODO keshav Generate Random Color Here
     message.setColor(getRandomMaterialColor("400"));
     messages.add(message); 
}
```

=============================================================

```
  private int getRandomMaterialColor(String typeColor) {
        int returnColor = Color.GRAY;
        int arrayId = getResources().getIdentifier("mdcolor_" + typeColor, "array", getPackageName());

        if (arrayId != 0) {
            TypedArray colors = getResources().obtainTypedArray(arrayId);
            int index = (int) (Math.random() * colors.length());
            returnColor = colors.getColor(index, Color.GRAY);
            colors.recycle();
        }
        return returnColor;
    }
```